# React Infinite scroll

Tags: reactjs, scroll, infinite-scroll

How to reinitialize the react infinite scroll component when a particular prop value change?

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.currentLanguage && (nextProps.currentLanguage !== this.props.currentLanguage)) {
  this.forceUpdate();
}
```

But the react infinite scroller is not initialised with the page 1 .

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know react-infinite-scroller but you may add a `key` prop to it and change it whenever you'd like to reinitialize. React will treat component with changed `key` as completely new component: it will unmount the old one and then initialize and mount new, fresh instance.

Comment: I have added the key , but still its not invoking the initial load method to fetch the results. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll

Comment: Are you changing the key value when you want a initial load again?

Comment: Yes I have changing the key.